# In which situation val/var is necessary in Kotlin constructor parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin

Right code:

```
class MainActHandler(val weakActivity: WeakReference<Activity>): Handler() {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
        val trueAct = weakActivity.get() ?: return
        if (msg?.what == ConversationMgr.MSG_WHAT_NEW_SENTENCE){
            val sentence = msg.obj as String?
            trueAct.conversation.text = sentence
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg)
    }
}
```

cannot be resolved code:

```
class MainActHandler(weakActivity: WeakReference<Activity>): Handler() {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
        val trueAct = weakActivity.get() ?: return
        if (msg?.what == ConversationMgr.MSG_WHAT_NEW_SENTENCE){
            val sentence = msg.obj as String?
            trueAct.conversation.text = sentence
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg)
    }
}
```

[cannot be resolved code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gMv.png)

The only difference is the "val" has been  deleted and cannot be resolve.

**Which might be important is that it's a inner class.**

**BUT**

This one class without "val/var" in constructor parameter is working:

```
class BookInfo(convrMgr: ConversationMgr, id: String, queue: RequestQueue, queueTag:String) {

val TAG = "BookInfo"
var title: String? = ""

init {
    val url = "https://api.douban.com/v2/book/$id"
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                Log.d(TAG + " Response", response.substring(0))
                // Parse JSON from String value
                val parser = Parser()
                val jsonObj: JsonObject =
                        parser.parse(StringBuilder(response.substring(0))) as JsonObject
                // Initial book title of book properties.
                title = jsonObj.string("title")
                Log.d(TAG + " Book title", title)
                convrMgr.addNewMsg(title)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error -> Log.e(TAG + " Error", error.toString()) })
    // Set the tag on the request.
    stringRequest.tag = queueTag
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

}

And if I add var/val before "queue: RequestQueue", I'll get suggestion:

"Constructor parameter is never used as a property less. This inspection reports primary constructor parameters that can have 'val' or 'var' removed. Unnecessary usage of 'val' and 'var' in primary constructor consumes unnecessary memory."

I am just confused about it.

Answer (score 134):

When you write `val`/`var` within the constructor, it declares a property inside the class. When you do not write it, it is simply a parameter passed to the primary constructor, where you can access the parameters within the `init` block or use it to initialize other properties. For example,

```
class User(val id: Long, email: String) {
    val hasEmail = email.isNotBlank()    //email can be accessed here
    init {
        //email can be accessed here

        //id can be accessed here
    }
    
    fun getEmail(){
        //email can't be accessed here

        //id can be accessed here
    }
}
```

> Constructor parameter is never used as a property

This suggestion is saying that you do not use this property in place apart from the initialization. So, it suggests you to remove this property from the class.

Comment: Good explanation.  According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html), specifying `val` or `var` on a "parameter" of a constructor turns the parameter in a "property". The term  ["parameter"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#parameters) is the name of a variable in a function's signature.  A constructor is a type of function.  Meanwhile, a ["property"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields) is a getter and/or setter on the class that may also have a field to store data.

Comment: this is an awesome explanation. i tried reading the documentation many many times and i didn't get this. thankyou

Answer (score 31):

Constructor parameters must use `var` or `val` when they are used as a property elsewhere in the class. They do not need to be properties if they are only used for class initialization.

In the example below, the parameter must be a property (`var` or `val`) because it is used in a method:

```
class A(val number: Int) {
    fun foo() = number
}
```

In this other example, the parameter is only used to initialize the class, so it does not need to be a property:

```
class B(number: Int): A(number) {
    init {
        System.out.println("number: $number")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This might be a late answer but the magic lies under the hood:

Based on `@BakaWaii's` answer:

Putting var/val will make the variable a property of the class and not putting it will make it a parameter of only the constructor function.

So what does it mean, to understand lets look into some code:

```kotlin
class Test(a: Int){}
```

Now Lets see the decompiled java code:

```java
public final class Test {
   public Test(int a) {
   }
}
```

So now if I try to access `a` using the object of `Test()` like the below code:

```java
Test t = new Test(10);
t.a //Error
```

It will give me error. `Unresolved reference: a`. Why because `a` is a parameter of the constructor only.

Now if we put var/val in the paramater like below:

```kotlin
class Test(var a: Int){}
```

The decompliked Java code will become:

```java
public final class Test {
   private int a;

   public final int getA() {
      return this.a;
   }

   public final void setA(int var1) {
      this.a = var1;
   }

   public Test(int a) {
      this.a = a;
   }
}
```

Thus it will not only give you a class property but also give you getter/setters for setting the values.

Now the next question arises if the field `a` is `private` how can it be accessed. Simple answer in Java you cannot, i.e. if you are calling the KT class from a Java you will not be able to assign value of `a` like `Test(1).a = 10` but will have to use `Test(1).setA(5)`.
But as kotlin internally handles getters/setters Test(1).a = 5 will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

For @Parcelize to work you need to open up the super's properties and override them in the child:

````
abstract class Goal(open var number: Int, open var name: String) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
class OperationalGoal(override var number: Int, override var name: String, var description: String) : Goal(number, name)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms, use `var` or `val` in class constructor parameters when you want to use that variable, say, inside a method within that class. Thus you're effectively turning them into [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html) and not *just* mere constructor or method `parameters`.

```
class User(var name: String, age: Int) {
    var str = "John"
    var num = 18

    fun setName(){
        name = str // due to using var on our class constructor parameter, we can access the constructor variable *name* inside this setter method. *name* is a property parameter thanks to the var keyword.
    }

    fun setAge(){
        age = num // this will result in a compiler error, because *age* is just a parameter, notice that var wasn't used in the *age* parameter within the class constructor, which means we can't access it like we did with *name*
    }
    
}
```

[Run this Kotlin Playground code to get a clearer idea of what's going on.](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)