# What is the difference if I remove the 'var' keyword in a class?

Tags: kotlin

Could you tell me what the difference between Code A and Code B is?

**Code A**

```
class Person(firstName: String) {
}
```

**Code B**

```
class Person(val firstName: String) {
}
```

Comment: Code A: the variable will be disponible in the `init{}` and for the intialization of your variable in the top of your class. Code B: the vaariable will be disponible in the all class, and can't be changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In which situation val/var is necessary in Kotlin constructor parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821929/in-which-situation-val-var-is-necessary-in-kotlin-constructor-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**first** one just as set an argument to your constructor to set to class member's.

**second** you already created a member variable firstName and you pass the incoming data to it.

second code equals :

```
class Person(firstName: String) {
    val firstName:String?
    init{
       this.firstName = firstName
    }
}
```

To be clear to you let us try this code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var person = Person("Stackoverflow")
    println(person.firstName)
}

class Person(val firstName: String) {

}
```

**OUTPUT**
Stackoverflow

okey let us try the first code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var person = Person("mohamed")
    println(person.firstName)
}

class Person( firstName: String) {

}
```

**OUTPUT**
Compiler error

> Unresolved reference: firstName