# Kotlin constructor ArrayAdapter not recognized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I have an issue with extending ArrayAdapter in Kotlin.

Here the code:

```
class SpinnerArrayAdapter(context: Context?, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<Pair<Long, String>>) : ArrayAdapter<Pair<Long, String>>(context, resource, list) {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size //error list is unresolved
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Not related to the ArrayAdapter extend. My problem was the constructor understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't declare you constructor args as `val` or `var` you can only access them inside the `init` block as they're not properties:

```
class Test(context: Context) {

    private lateinit var applicationContext: Context

    init {
        applicationContext = context.applicationContext
    }
}
```

If you need to access them outside the `init` block, you should mark them as properties by using `val` or `var` depending on your needs:

```
class Test(val context: Context) {

    private lateinit var applicationContext: Context

    fun test() {
        applicationContext = context.applicationContext
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your problem and I found the same issue.

But by calling your constructor with the val keywords, it's working.

```
class SpinnerArrayAdapter(context: Context?, val resource: Int, val list: ArrayList<Pair<Long, String>>) : ArrayAdapter<Pair<Long, String>>(context, resource, list) {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

Anyway, I don't know why the val keywords is required in this case. I'll will dig to find the problem.

Comment: @Sqrt You may take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822035/8343333

Comment: Yes thank you for your comment. It's clearer now. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    var languages = arrayOf("English", "French", "Spanish", "Hindi", "Russian", "Telugu", "Chinese", "German", "Portuguese", "Arabic", "Dutch", "Urdu", "Italian", "Tamil", "Persian", "Turkish", "Other")

    var spinner:Spinner? = null
    var textView_msg:TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView_msg = this.msg

        spinner = this.spinner_sample
        spinner!!.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and languages array
        val aa = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages)
        // Set layout to use when the list of choices appear
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        // Set Adapter to Spinner
        spinner!!.setAdapter(aa)

    }

    override fun onItemSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>, arg1: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        textView_msg!!.text = "Selected : "+languages[position]
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {

    }
}
```

It may help you , try it.

Comment: Not working in my case, I really need to use my Adapter, since I will need to pass an object, and my UI will have a text view and a custom color.

Comment: Mean you are creating custom array adapter.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to use my Custom array adapter, right now I just passed  a Pair<Long, String>, but It will be an Object later.